# PHP session variables not being set

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble with PHP session variables: I try setting the variables, and they can't be read even in the same file, much less another file.

Sorry if the question has been asked before, but I can't find anything that doesn't say "make sure you have `session_start()` at the beginning of the file."

Lines 1, 2, & 3 of file:

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.save_path','/home/[username]/session_data'); // Just in case, points to a correct directory
    session_start();
```

Later, after username validation, and login, the variables are set, and code tries to `echo` them out:

```
$_SESSION['login'] == "true";
$_SESSION['username'] == $username;
$_SESSION['password'] == sha1($password);
//header("Location: [admin page hidden]"); // Code would normally redirect to admin page (commented out for debugging), and exit
//exit;
echo "Username: ".$username."<br />"; // The following 4 lines try to print out the data
echo "Password: ".$password."<br />";
echo "Secure Password: ".sha1($password)."<br />";
echo "Session Username: ".$_SESSION['username']."<br />";
```

The output is:

```
Username: root
Password: [correct password]
Secure Password: [correct sha1 version of password]
Session Username:
```

The secure password (`sha1`, what is checked) matches what is in the database file, I checked.  Nothing comes out for the session variables, even though it was created 7 lines previously.  The directory that I pointed the save path to just has a blank file for the session.

Does anyone have any clue why this doesn't work, or advice on how to proceed?  Any helpful response is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following lines are the cause of the problem :

```
$_SESSION['login'] == "true";
$_SESSION['username'] == $username;
$_SESSION['password'] == sha1($password);
```

Those lines do pretty much nothing : they **compare** what's before the `==` with what's after it ; and do nothing with the result of that comparison.

To **assign** values to variables, you should use **ONE `=`**, and not two :

```
$_SESSION['login'] = "true";
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = sha1($password);
```

Those three lines **assign** what's on the right of the `=` to what's on its left.

In PHP :

- **`==`** is a [**comparison operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
- while **`=`** is an [**assignment operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Comment: Right, of course.  I've been coding in PHP for about a year, and this is the first times I've screwed that up...  Must have been pretty tired when I wrote that code.

Comment: Huhu ^^ sometimes, having another person look at your code helps :-) *(It's the kind of mistake we all do... and never see it when it's in our own code ^^ )*

Comment: Yup.  Thanks for the answer.  I have another question, if you might be able to answer it (would SO rather I create another question?):  Is there an easy way to check what variables are set, through the browser, or am I better off trying to print off most of the variables?

Comment: If the question is a new one *(i.e. something not exactly related to this one)*, you'd better create a new question, I suppose : it would be pushed at the top of the questions list, it would allow other people to answer, ...

Answer (score 2):

You are using `==`, which is an equality test.  Instead use `=`.

Answer (score 0):

What does the webserver's log says? It must be some rights issue.